# bg-repeat create td when iteration is to low

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi guys I have this table in my angular app. You can order three types of meals breakfast, lunch and dinner. So I use a colspan of 3 but if the user only ordered 2 times food how can I add the last td ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the german code.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
          <th>Ermäßigt</th>
          <th colspan="3">Food</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="teil in ctrl.teilnehmerList">
          <td>{{teil.vorname}}</td>
          <td>{{teil.nachname}}</td>
          <td>{{teil.gebDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>
            <i ng-show="teil.gender == 'w'" class="fa fa-female"></i>
            <i ng-show="teil.gender == 'm'" class="fa fa-male"></i>
          </td>
          <td ng-repeat="essen in teil.einnahmen">
            <i ng-show="essen.typ !='erm' | essen.typ !='norm'" class="fa fa-check"></i>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.removeTeil(teil)"><span
              class="glyphicon  glyphicon-remove "></span></button>
          </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an entire table for the food. Then, you will not have to worry about the colspan at all.

Comment: that is a nice idea but then I cant put a second header in my main table

Comment: I don't fully understand the second header part. Can you show a JSFiddle

Comment: Got it! Don't hard-code 3. Use the data to compute the same. e.g. teil.getSelectedFoodCount() and also put the show/hide on td.

This will ensure that your colspans are in sync. Its a little crude fix.